# Element heights

Tags: html, dom

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">foobar</div>
</div>
```

Why is outer say, only 10px heigh, when inner is say, 20px high. Shouldn't outer be the maximum size to enclose inner?

Comment: can you provide the css you have that relates to these two elements please

Comment: …that depends on the display property

Comment: I didn't have any css on it. Remove your -1 dude. Not cool.

Comment: @haxxton Why? This is such a general question on CSS basics – you don't need no code to help here. But on the other hand this is already described in detail on countless CSS tutorials.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't even asking for css help. It's the height that Google Chrome is rendering the elements. I was asking a general question as to why when I thought the standard was to make the outer element the hight of all inner elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be documented CSS behavior which depends on a number of properties; see [MDN: Block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)